# Run script from another one in different directory

Tags: python, path

I am trying to run `results.py` from `app.py` located in a different directory. I have the following mapping:

```py
App/
---model/
--------model.csv
---results/
----------results.py
---app.py
```

**results.py**

```py
def get_file():
    df = pd.read_csv('../model/model.csv')
    ...
```

I tried to change the working directory but I still have `FileNotFoundError`

**app.py**

```py
curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'results')
subprocess.Popen("ls", cwd=path)
get_file()
```

Comment: `subprocess.call(["python","results.py"], cwd ="results")` ?

Comment: this actually runs it as main as in what's inside `if __name__=='__main__'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix can be

```
def get_file():
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv('../model/model.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
       df = pd.read_csv('./model/model.csv')
```

Comment: I did import the module from `results` of course. The problem resides in  `df = pd.read_csv('../model/model.csv')`  because of the path but don't know how to fix it

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen So the real issue here is finding the csv file?

Comment: If you print `curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` inside `results.py` - what do you get?

Comment: I tried that and it gives me the correct directory. When I run `results.py` as main it works just fine because `../model` exists however if  run it from `app.py` it doesn't find the csv file because simply `../model` doesn't exist but `./model` does

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen I have change my answer to make it support `../model` and `./model` This should work

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to run results.py from app.py located in a different directory

you can create in your path 'results/' file __init__.py:

```
#file __init__.py

from .results import get_file
```

and then in app.py you can call this:

```
import results

results.get_file()
```